# How to prove $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ are supermartingale and $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is convergence to -7

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, stochastic-processes

Let $p \in [0  , \frac{1}{2}] $ and $\eta_{i}$ be i.i.d random variables and $P(\eta_{i}=1)=p$ and $P(\eta_{i}=-1)=1-p$ and $\mathcal F_{n}=\sigma(\eta_{1},\cdots,\eta_{n})$ and $X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_{i}$ and $Y_{n}=X_{T(-7)  \wedge  n}  $(means martingale/submartingale/supermartingale when stopped by a stopping time) . 
     show that

1. $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and  $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ are supermartingale or matigale or submartingale.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos.subscript in $Y_{n\in \mathbb N}$ means stopping time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_{n}) = E(\eta_{n+1}+X_{n}\mid \mathcal F_{n})$$
$$=E(\eta_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_{n}) +E(X_{n}\mid \mathcal F_{n}) =E(\eta_{n+1}) + X_n$$

Now look up the definitions.

Analogously for $Y_n$ - if you understand its subscript (I don't).

Comment: .subscript in $Y_{n\in \mathbb N}$ means stopping time.

Comment: can you solve the  $Y_{n}$

Comment: You have deleted the part referring to $Y_n$, and also, you have received an answer for $Y_n$ in math.SE, an answer that you have accepted. Why do you need another answer?